# using variable to retrieve item from array

Tags: jquery, arrays

I am wanting to set a variable to change the number value to get the correct array item

Console.log this and i get what i need , but any attempts made to add a variable are not working

```
// This works
lastKickoffTime = m_nfl_schedule_ar.w_5.slice(-1).pop().kickoff
```

Attempts that have not worked

```
weekNum = "5";

lastKickoffTime = m_nfl_schedule_ar.['w_'+weekNum].slice(-1).pop().kickoff

lastKickoffTime = m_nfl_schedule_ar.w_[weekNum].slice(-1).pop().kickoff

lastKickoffTime = m_nfl_schedule_ar.w_weekNum.slice(-1).pop().kickoff

lastKickoffTime = m_nfl_schedule_ar.w_+weekNum+.slice(-1).pop().kickoff

lastKickoffTime = m_nfl_schedule_ar.w_'+weekNum+'.slice(-1).pop().kickoff
```

Comment: It would help much if you include the data of m_nfl_schedule_ar so we could reproduce this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lastKickoffTime = m_nfl_schedule_ar.['w_'+weekNum].slice(-1).pop().kickoff` is almost right. should be:

```
lastKickoffTime = m_nfl_schedule_ar['w_'+weekNum].slice(-1).pop().kickoff
```

Comment: now why in the heck does it work without the dot , makes no sense to me , but thansk !

Comment: it's either "dot notation" or "bracket notation"

Comment: `.slice(-1).pop()` can be replaced by `.at(-1)`.